# Hall-sensored BLDC motor does not spin and triggers a fault condition

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, motordriver

I've been trying unsuccessfully to run a hall-sensored hoverboard BLDC motor (24V, 250W) using the [MP6532](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp6532.html) chip. The PWM signal is generated using `TIM1` in `STM32F103`. Voltage across a potentiometer is read and it proportionally adjusts the duty cycle in software. As I start ramping up the pot, at about a duty cycle of 20% the motor spurts into a spin and then the `nFAULT` triggers. Also, the `nFAULT` pin is very sensitive. It has a test pad to monitor its state and even touching the pad with a multimeter probe triggers the fault condition. Since its an open drain output, its pulled up with a `10K` resistor to `+3.3V`. Manually turning the wheel also triggers the fault condition. Can anyone help me figure out what is happening here and how to debug this?

EDIT: The schematic and layouts are [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gyH199Cq981rVFMkgvAUejEnRg518hEJ/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Show schematics, board layout, how you connected STM32 to this IC.

Comment: It seems very odd that touching an output would cause a fault on a BLDC controller. Can you reduce the voltage? Use less than 24V?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič The schematic and layouts are [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gyH199Cq981rVFMkgvAUejEnRg518hEJ/view?usp=sharing). Layer 1 is VIN, Layer 2 is GND, Layer 3 is 5V and Layer 4 is LSS. There is a 50mR current sense resistor between LSS and GND.

Comment: @mkeith I'd probably be able to go down by about 2V but the motor definitely needs more than 20V.

Comment: What is the OCREF setting?

Comment: There is a voltage divider there that sets it to 2V.

Comment: Have you tried to lock the rotor and increase the DT?

Comment: I'll give it a shot. How do I lock the rotor?

Comment: I opened the DT jumper (setting the DT to about 6uS) and still the same issue. Maybe I need to use a stronger pull-up?

Comment: Please add images of the schematics and layout to your post -- don't just link to them. Not everyone can/wants to access Google Drive.

Comment: When I said "reduce the voltage," what I meant was to temporarily reduce the voltage to see if the fault still happens when you run at low voltage. It seems like as soon as you start spinning you get a fault. My thinking was that maybe lowering the voltage would make the system less sensitive that way. But it sounds like you found a big problem with current sensing so maybe you need to fix that first. They key thing you need to do is figure out what the driver thinks the fault is. Is it phase over-current or short circuit or what? Then go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current sense resistor seems to be connected by just a small via.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT:

You have an entire copper plane named LSS, so that bridge current spreads all over, instead of having an isolated plane with sense resistor. What is more weird, that the sense resistor is not even connected to that LSS plane.

[image]

Instead of having just a small plane with sense resistor:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks and you are correct. Strange that KiCad did not show an unconnected error in the DRC. Also I got it working... briefly. I recalculated the gate resistors and increased those to 68R from the existing 2R. Also closed the DT jumper again reconnecting the 200K resistor for the dead time. With this the motor turns and at one point the duty cycle came from 100% to 0% within a second. That burned out the 5V regulator. I replaced that but it now the 3.3V supply regulator on the Bluepill won't come on. Probably one of the internal traces blew out.

Comment: @electrophile If that answers the question, then please mark as accepted.

Comment: Would you know why the regulator burned out due to the sudden change in the duty cycle? Just trying to figure out what happened.

Comment: @electrophile Due to regenerative energy, when the motor was decelerating it became a generator and the inertial energy was transfered back to the DC link capacitor, if not enough capacitance the voltage has rised to high values.